# Taking screenshots in browser less execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to do web page automation using Phantomjs. As it is browser less execution , is there any way that I can get the screen shot of my test running,may be from the memory

Comment: This question as asked shows a shocking lack of research. A quick Google search for "How do I take a screenshot with WebDriver using PhantomJS" yields several links showing exactly how to do this. If there is something you've tried, but is not working, please include that in the question. As you present the situation currently, it seems like you've done nothing at all toward solving the problem, including reading the [Selenium documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this code and it worked. :)

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./screenshot/snap.png"));
```